# Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member '.three'

Tags: ios, swift

I have an extension on `UIFont` with my own custom font like this:

```
extension UIFont {
    static func myFont(_ size: MyFontSize) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: "My-Font", size: size.rawValue)!
    }
}

enum MyFontSize: CGFloat {
    case three = 16
}
```

However, every time I use this to set the font of a label it gives me an error that says `Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'three'` and `Type 'UIFont' has no member 'myFont'`.

I am setting the font like this:

```
myLabel.font = .myFont(.three)
```

Weirdly, this error only started appearing in the latest Xcode 13 beta, and it does actually still build fine. Is this just an Xcode beta bug?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your code compiles just fine for me, except for the part about `Styles` which you did not explain and I just deleted it.

Comment: @matt, Okay just solved it... I wasn't importing UIKit in the extension - I was importing Foundation. Weird that it still built and work despite giving a semi-error

Comment: It's weird for sure, but I regard that as a trivial typo, and there was nothing about the question that would elicit that answer, so voting to close.

Comment: This defeats dynamic type, you probably shouldn’t be doing this, in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by importing `UIKit` into the extension. I was importing `Foundation` instead and that was causing the error.